# Fetching single account from web3.eth

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to fetch the first account using `web3.eth.accounts[0]` using Truffle, but couldn't seem to make it work.

I'm using version 0.5.0. I read that the command is deprecated and have to use `web3.eth.getAccounts()` for asynchronous execution. The latter only displays an array of accounts connected to the local network.

How do I get a single account in this case? I wanted to pass `{ from: web3.eth.accounts[0] }` metadata to a public function in my contract.

Comment: You probably want to change the tag here from `solidity` to `web3.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function getAccount(id) {
    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    return accounts[id];
}
```

You'll need to execute `await getAccount(0)` from an `async` function of course (or use a `Promise`).